# How to create save button to jpg in flash?

Tags: android, actionscript-3, flash

How do I create a save button in flash.

I have project educational coloring book mobile based with flash ActionScript 3.0. So if we done coloring we can save image to jpg. I want create a save button for thsi image.

Comment: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ActionScript/3.0_UsingComponentsAS3/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9c65b32-7fac.html ActionScript's API docs might help you with the basics.

Answer (score 0):

Creating a button is easy :) it's what you want to do in the button.
Since the scope of your question is very large, I will point you in the directions you have to investigate:

1 - Convert a movieclip into a bitmapdata
2 - unse JPEGEncoder or PNGEncoder in as3corelib to convert BitmapData into a ByteArray.
3 - If it is an AIR project, investigate the File class in order to save the ByteArray on the local filesystem
4 - If it is Flash in the browser, you will need a backend script on the server to save the ByteArray as post data, and then download it on the local machine (Flash plugin in browser cannot save in local filesystem)

good luck